# How to use tab to ident multiple lines in textarea editor in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

I am looking for a solution that would enable me to use tab/shift-tab to change indentation of selected multiple lines in a textarea, like the markdown editor here.

So far I am looking for a Chrome solution.

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering about the same thing, below is a function that will indent/unindent what you selected and keep your selection intact. It uses 4 spaces, but you can change that in the "if(e.shiftKey)" bit to use only 2 spaces or tabs

```js
function supportTabIndentation(textarea) {
        const offsetToLineAndOffset = (lines, offset) => {
          let line = 0
          while (offset > lines[line].length && line < lines.length - 1) {
              offset = offset - lines[line].length - 1
              line++
          }
          return {line, offset}
      }
      const LineAndOffsetToOffset = (lines, line, offset) => {
          for (let i = 0; i < line; i++)
              offset += lines[i].length + 1

          return offset
      }

      textarea.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
          if (e.key == 'Tab') {
              e.preventDefault() 
              const lines = e.target.value.split('\n')
              const selection = [offsetToLineAndOffset(lines, textarea.selectionStart),
                  offsetToLineAndOffset(lines, textarea.selectionEnd)]
              for (var l = selection[0].line; l <= selection[1].line; l++) {
                  const originalLength = lines[l].length
                  if (e.shiftKey) {
                      lines[l] = lines[l].replace(/^ {0,4}/, '')
                  } else {
                      lines[l] = '    ' + lines[l]
                  }
                  // How much the line moved
                  const delta = lines[l].length - originalLength
                  // Update the user selection if it's on this line
                  selection.forEach((sel) => {
                      if (sel.line == l) {
                          sel.offset = Math.max(0, sel.offset + delta)
                      }
                  })
              }
              textarea.value = lines.join('\n')
              textarea.selectionStart = LineAndOffsetToOffset(lines, selection[0].line, selection[0].offset)
              textarea.selectionEnd = LineAndOffsetToOffset(lines, selection[1].line, selection[1].offset)
          }
      })
  }

      supportTabIndentation(document.getElementById('editor'))
```

```css
body{padding:0;margin:0;overflow:hidden;}
#editor{
  background:#333;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  height:100vh;
  width:100vw;
  border:none;
  resize:none;
  color:white; 
}
```

```html
<textarea id="editor">
Select
Lines
And
Tab
Or
Shift
Tab
</textarea>
```